# Queries related to Transitive Relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Let me assume that 'R' is a relation on 'A'. 'A' contains four elements {x,y,z,o}.

Also let x R y , y R z  and x R z . Now, my queries are :

Will 'R' be called a Transitive Relation if :

1) o is not related to any  element in 'A' under relation 'R'

2) o is related only to itself under relation 'R'

3) o is related to another element , say y , under relation 'R'

My answers : 1) Yes      2) Yes.     3) No

Am I correct?

Comment: It depends.  The phrasing of the question makes it ambiguous as to what else might be included in the relation.  The relations $\{(x,y),(y,z),(x,z)\}, \{(o,o),(x,y),(y,z),(x,z)\}$ and $\{(o,z),(x,y),(y,z),(x,z)\}$ are all transitive.  $\{(o,x),(x,y),(y,z),(x,z)\}$ is not transitive and neither is $\{(x,y),(y,z),(x,z),(z,y)\}$.  So, assuming nothing extra is added to the relation beyond the required $(x,y),(y,z),(x,z)$ from the problem statement and either none or exactly one pair of the form $(o,\star)$, the answers would be 1) Yes, 2) Yes, 3) It depends.

Comment: Thank you. But why isn't {(x,y),(y,z),(x,z),(z,y)} Transitive?

Comment: Because in that example $(y,z)$ and $(z,y)$ are in the relation however $(y,y)$ is not (*among other missing pairs*).  Do not confuse yourself that often the definition of transitivity is written using variable names $x,y,z$ and that in your example you have opted to also use $x,y,z$... transitivity means that if you have a first thing that is related to a second thing, and if you have that same second thing that is related to a third, then the first thing should be related to the third... keeping in mind that any of the first, second, or third things could be identical.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming  $x$R$y$, $y$R$z$, $xRz$ is still valid for all 3 questions, then you are correct.

3) having $o$R$y$ makes it not transitive because $o$ is not related to $z$

Answer (score 0):

Actually the set A doesn't play vital role to define R is transitive, R is transitive if R contains (x,z), when ever it contains(x,y) and (y,z).

So using above argument the answers yes, yes, no are correct.

In third question, o is related y is given, and y is related to z is already know, but is o is related to z or not we don't know. So third question we can decide only when we the relation between o and z.